# Trigger Conflicts in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, triggers

We have a system that needs bilk update and insert process in database, So we have created trigger for updating the Table.

We are running the trigger only if the `trigger_call` field set at our mysql query. It's working fine but Sometime the trigger conflicts with the trigger calling query.

My Trigger:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateAvailabilityUpdateMain` BEFORE UPDATE ON `base`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        DECLARE vSite VARCHAR(40);
        IF (NEW.availability <> OLD.availability && NEW.trigger_cal=1) THEN
            SET new.trigger_cal =0;
            IF (NEW.availability > OLD.availability) THEN
                SET vSite = NEW.availability - OLD.availability;
                UPDATE reservation_table 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability + vSite >=0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date; 
                UPDATE room_rate_types_base 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability + vSite >=0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date;
                UPDATE room_rate_types_additional 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability + vSite >=0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability + vSite WHEN availability + vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date;
            ELSEIF (NEW.availability < OLD.availability) THEN
                SET vSite = OLD.availability - NEW.availability;
                UPDATE reservation_table 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability - vSite >=0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date;
                UPDATE room_rate_types_base 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability - vSite >=0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date;
                UPDATE room_rate_types_additional 
                SET availability = CASE WHEN availability - vSite >=0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id = 0 THEN availability - vSite WHEN availability - vSite < 0 AND individual_channel_id != 0 THEN 0 END
                WHERE owner_id = new.owner_id AND hotel_id = new.hotel_id AND room_id = new.room_id AND separate_date = new.separate_date;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END
```

Error:

```
Can't update table 'base' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

During the update, the error occurs.

```
UPDATE `base` SET `availability` = 1, `trigger_cal` = 1 WHERE `date` =  '09/09/2016'.
```

We are not getting the error often. Sometimes we are facing the issue. We have searched lot, but couldn't find the reason to avoid this issue

Can anyone point us, what we are missing, why this error occurs and how to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: This error means that you are trying to update the table `base` inside a trigger on table `base` (maybe with `update base` directly in the trigger, maybe indirectly by a trigger that gets triggered by your trigger), which is not allowed. It should actually always result in an error, not just sometimes. Please add the trigger code.

Comment: @Solarflare, I have added my trigger

Comment: That trigger is correct and should not create that error message. Check in your 3 other tables if you have a trigger that updates `base`. (Probably the table with the least amount of rows).